# Fuzzy Join Using Time and Geo-coordinates in R

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, geospatial, spatial

There two data frames with disparate information. The only columns they have in common are datetime and lat/long fields. Can one create a third data frame using R or an R package (or possibly Python/Pandas) that takes a subset of rows from both data frames by similar date and lat/long fields? The joins should be fuzzy, not exact, plus/minus an hr and tenth a degree.

Input Example:

```
df_1
Datetime            Latitude    Longitude
2018-10-01 08:27:10 34.8014080  103.8499800
2018-09-30 04:55:51 43.3367432  44.158934
2018-02-28 17:03:27 37.0399910  115.6672080

df_2
Datetime            Latitude    Longitude
2018-10-01 08:57:10 34.8014080  103.8999800
2018-09-30 04:55:51 43.3367432  48.158934
2018-02-27 17:03:27 37.0399910  115.6672080
```

Output Example:

```
fuzzy_geo_temporal_join(df_1, df_2, time = 60, lat = 0.01, long = 0.01)
df_3
df_1 Datetime       df_1 Lat    df_1 Long    df_2 Datetime       df_2 Lat    df_2 Long
2018-10-01 08:27:10 34.8014080  103.8499800  2018-10-01 08:57:10 34.8014080  103.8999800
```

Note: In this example, the first one matches and  gets placed into the new data frame. Due to the fuzzy parameters given, the second and third one do not.

Comment: Check out the fuzzyjoin package. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/README.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a job for a non-equi join, using `data.table`!

```
library( data.table )
```

**sample data**

```
dt1 <- fread( "Datetime,            Latitude,    Longitude
2018-10-01 08:27:10, 34.8014080,  103.8499800
2018-09-30 04:55:51, 43.3367432,  44.158934
2018-02-28 17:03:27, 37.0399910,  115.6672080", header = T)

dt2  <- fread("Datetime,            Latitude,    Longitude
2018-10-01 08:57:10, 34.8014080,  103.8999800
2018-09-30 04:55:51, 43.3367432,  48.158934
2018-02-27 17:03:27, 37.0399910,  115.6672080", header = T)
```

**data-preparation**

```
#set datetimes to POSIXct
dt1[, Datetime := as.POSIXct( Datetime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") ]
dt2[, `:=`(Datetime = as.POSIXct( Datetime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" ) )]
```

**join**

```
#create boundaries
dt2[, `:=`(Datetime_max = Datetime + 3600,
           Datetime_min = Datetime - 3600,
           Latitude_max = Latitude + 0.1,
           Latitude_min = Latitude - 0.1,
           Longitude_max = Longitude + 0.1,
           Longitude_min = Longitude - 0.1) ]

#perform non-equi join
dt1[ dt2, on = .( Datetime <= Datetime_max, 
                  Datetime >= Datetime_min, 
                  Latitude <= Latitude_max, 
                  Latitude >= Latitude_min, 
                  Longitude <= Longitude_max, 
                  Longitude >= Longitude_min ),
     nomatch = 0L]
```

**result**

```
#               Datetime Latitude Longitude          Datetime.1 Latitude.1 Longitude.1          i.Datetime i.Latitude i.Longitude
# 1: 2018-10-01 09:57:10 34.90141       104 2018-10-01 07:57:10   34.70141       103.8 2018-10-01 08:57:10   34.80141       103.9
```

Comment: This definitely works on the test data provided. Hoping that this works on the real data.

Answer (score 0):

This might work...

```
install.packages("fuzzyjoin")
library(fuzzyjoin)

close_dates <- difference_inner_join(df1, df2, by = "Datetime", max_dist = 60)
close_lats <-  difference_inner_join(close_dates, df2, by = "Latitude", max_dist = 0.01)
df3 <- difference_inner_join(close_lats, df2, by = "Longitude", max_dist = 0.01)
```

Comment: Thanks DJ, what could be going wrong if I constantly receive the error "Error: data_frames can only contain 1d atomic vectors and lists" from running this code?

Comment: I didn't run my code because I wasn't sure how you were storing your dates, and it turns out my example has unaddressed details. That error comes from the difference_inner_join() producing new column names, so the next join doesn't work. I usually handle my dates using the lubridate package, but it isn't clear to me how to use that in the max_dist argument. You might want to just go with @Wimpel 's data table solution. Next time it would help if you build up minimal data frames for us to practice with.

Comment: My apologies, I did not forsee how the data frame difference was going to impact the results!