# Merging values from 2 different datasets within a certain time interval into a single dataset (R)

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, lubridate, stringr

I have two separate datasets: df1 and df2. I would like to create a new dataset, df3 that would match the endtime column of df1 with the sent column of df2 if the datetimes are within 20 seconds of each other.

```
 df1

 endtime                     ID

 1/7/2020  1:35:08 AM         A
 1/7/2020  1:39:00 AM         B
 1/20/2020 1:45:00 AM         C



 df2

sent                         ID

1/7/2020  1:35:20 AM          E
1/7/2020  1:42:00 AM          F
1/20/2020 1:55:00 AM          G
1/20/2020 2:00:00 AM          E
```

This is my desired output for df3. There is only one row, because there are only two values that match the condition of being within 20 seconds of the endtime and sent columns.

```
endtime                  sent 

1/7/2020 1:35:08 AM      1/7/2020  1:35:20 AM
```

Here is the dput:

```
df1

structure(list(endtime = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1/10/2020 1:45:00 AM", 
"1/7/2020 1:35:08 AM", "1/7/2020 1:39:00 AM"), class = "factor"), 
ID = structure(1:3, .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names =   c(NA, 
 -3L))





 df2

 structure(list(sent = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1/20/2020 1:55:00 AM", 
 "1/20/2020 2:00:00 AM", "1/7/2020 1:35:20 AM", "1/7/2020 1:42:00 AM"
 ), class = "factor"), ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("E", 
"F", "G"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

This is what I have tried:

I am thinking of performing a left join and matching the values, or I can use merge(), but the tricky part is matching the values with the conditional statement. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1, df2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no common column to join, we can use `crossing` to create all combinations of rows and then `filter` the ones which fit the criteria.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  rename(ID1 = 'ID') %>%
  tidyr::crossing(df2) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(endtime, sent), lubridate::mdy_hms) %>%
  filter(abs(difftime(sent, endtime, 'secs')) < 20)

#  endtime             ID1   sent                ID   
#  <dttm>              <fct> <dttm>              <fct>
#1 2020-01-07 01:35:08 A     2020-01-07 01:35:20 E
```

Comment: is there a way to reveal the data that did not match the criteria? (almost like an anti-join? @Ronak

Comment: If you just change the sign from `<` to `>` it should give you that.

Comment: Hi @Ronak will this work for datasets around 1000 rows? and how would I avoid 'repeats' . I am wanting unique matches, non-repeating

Comment: Yes, this will work for dataset with 1000 rows. You can use `unique` or `distinct` at the end to get unique rows.

Comment: Ok when I changed the operator sign, I did not get unmatched criteria,  I am not sure what I am doing wrong @ronak

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this if your datasets are too big to make the cartesian product:

```r
df1 %>% 
    split(1:NROW(.)) %>% 
    map( ~merge(.x,
                df2[ abs(difftime(df2$sent, .x$endtime, units='s')) < 20, ],
                by=NULL) ) %>%
    bind_rows()
```

### EDIT

*TLDR*

Use the [non-equi join from data.table](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/data.table.html), it has the best performance overall.

```r
dt1 = as.data.table(df1)
dt2 = as.data.table(df2)

dt1[, `:=`(endtime_min = endtime - 20, endtime_max = endtime + 20) ]
dt1[dt2,
    .(ID, ID1, endtime, sent), 
    on = .(endtime_min < sent, endtime_max > sent), nomatch = 0L, allow.cartesian=T]
```

*Longer version*

The answer I posted would be better in scenarios where the data frames are too big, since doing the cross join first yields a data frame with as many rows as the product of the number of rows from both data frames. By first filtering and after joining, it avoids the unnecessary memory allocation. However, it has the overhead of for each row of `df1`, checking if there are any rows to match in the `df2`.

Another use case where this answer would be better is when one of the data frames is much smaller than the other, even if they aren't that big. I ran some benchmarks to check this.

However, after coming across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52604279/4110792), and making the version of the solution in data.table for the question presented by the OP, none of the answers compares to the performance of this implementation.

The tests I ran used the datasets given by the OP, where to simulate a larger dataset I simply replicated those datasets a certain amount of times. There were 2 tests that I did:

1. Replicated both datasets the same amount of times
2. Fixed the size of `df1` and replicated `df2`

For each test, I measured the median execution time for the accepted answer (`merge_filter`), my original answer (`filter_merge`) and the data.table solution (`datatable`).

Prior to running the tests, I prepared both `df1` and `df2` to have the right datatypes, and renamed the column `ID` from `df1` to `ID1`. For the data.table solution, I converted both data frames into their `data.tables` counterparts, `dt1` and `dt2`.

Regarding each method, I have to do some changes, mainly using `merge(..., by=NULL)` instead of `crossing(...)` since the last one doesn't support cross joining with duplicate rows, removing all the duplicate rows from the resulting dataset.

Here is the code I used to run the tests:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

run_test = function(n, n1=n, n2=n) {
    df1 = bind_rows(rep(list(df1_op), n1))
    df2 = bind_rows(rep(list(df1_op), n2))
    dt1 = as.data.table(df1)
    dt2 = as.data.table(df2)

    microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
        merge_filter = df1 %>%
            merge(df2, by=NULL) %>%
            filter(abs(difftime(sent, endtime, 'secs')) < 20),

        filter_merge = df1 %>% 
            split(1:NROW(.)) %>% 
            map(~merge( .x,
                        df2[ abs(difftime(df2$sent, .x$endtime, units='s')) < 20, ],
                        by=NULL) ) %>%
            bind_rows(),

        datatable={
            dt1[, `:=`(endtime_min = endtime - 20, endtime_max = endtime + 20) ]
            dt1[dt2,
                .(ID, ID1, endtime, sent), 
                on = .(endtime_min < sent, endtime_max > sent), nomatch = 0L, allow.cartesian=T]
        }
    )
}

test_1_list = list()
for( n in c(1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500) ) {
    test_1_list[[ toString(n) ]] <- run_test(n)
}

test_2_list = list()
for( n in c(1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 
            1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 50000) ) {
    test_2_list[[ toString(n) ]] <- run_test(n, n1=1)
}
```

And here are the results for test 1 and 2 respectively:

[image]

[image]

### EDIT 2

You can do a non-equi left join like this:

`filter_merge`

```r
df1 %>% 
    split(1:NROW(.)) %>% 
    map( ~merge(mutate(.x, k=1),
                df2 %>%
                    filter( abs(difftime(df2$sent, .x$endtime, units='s')) < 20 ) %>%
                    mutate(k=1),
                by="k",
                all.x=T) %>%
            select(-k) ) %>%
    bind_rows() %>%
    select(ID1, endtime, ID, sent)

#   ID1             endtime   ID                sent
# 1   A 2020-01-07 01:35:08    E 2020-01-07 01:35:20
# 2   B 2020-01-07 01:39:00 <NA>                <NA>
# 3   C 2020-01-10 01:45:00 <NA>                <NA>
```

`datatable`

```r
dt1[, `:=`(endtime_min = endtime - 20, endtime_max = endtime + 20) ]
dt2[dt1,
    .(i.ID1, i.endtime, x.ID, x.sent), 
    on = .(sent > endtime_min, sent < endtime_max), allow.cartesian=T]

#    i.ID1           i.endtime x.ID              x.sent
# 1:     A 2020-01-07 01:35:08    E 2020-01-07 01:35:20
# 2:     B 2020-01-07 01:39:00 <NA>                <NA>
# 3:     C 2020-01-10 01:45:00 <NA>                <NA>
```

Comment: Hello thank you, so the first solution doesn’t work if the datasets are too large? Can you tell me the limit? Thank you

Comment: Oh wow thank you for this. Interesting! I will analyze this! @MkWTF , is there a way to reveal the data that does not match the criteria? (almost like an anti-join?)

Comment: I think you just need to invert the join condition in any of the methods to achieve that, except for the data.table solution. For this last one you'd probably need to make two joins (one for values lower than min, and another for values greater than max) and then bind the results together.

Comment: Correction: not invert the join condition, but negate it.

Comment: I added the solution with left join. Sorry @TanishaHudson I had forgotten about that requirement